# How to make the inflated views links to a new activity

Tags: android

I am coming from a web development background (PHP). In my example, I retrieve a list of users, with their profile image, first and last name. Now I want each row of data (which represents a user), to open an activity to that clicked user profile.

**On the web, it was simple by adding links with PHP. But how do I do that with Java and Android?**

Right now, I managed to create a simple list that is fetched as a String array with simple text. But it's not clickable.
This is my current code: (I didn't include the XML files code, I don't think it's relevant)

**For test purpose, you see I use an array of Strings with 15 rows of data, and each String is acting as "first name" and "last name" - again, just for testings.
I want to know how to make those lines of data clickable and send to a new activity with the user's details. (If I can "mimic" data that will be sent to that new activity that would be great!)

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    package com.example.recycleview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        String[] myDataset = new String[16];
        myDataset[0] = "Data0";
        myDataset[1] = "Data1";
        myDataset[2] = "Data2";
        myDataset[3] = "Data3";
        myDataset[4] = "Data4";
        myDataset[5] = "Data5";
        myDataset[6] = "Data6";
        myDataset[7] = "Data7";
        myDataset[8] = "Data8";
        myDataset[9] = "Data9";
        myDataset[10] = "Data10";
        myDataset[11] = "Data11";
        myDataset[12] = "Data12";
        myDataset[13] = "Data13";
        myDataset[14] = "Data14";
        myDataset[15] = "Data15";

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java:**

```
    package com.example.recycleviewe;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView upTv;
        public TextView downTv;
        public View layout;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;
            upTv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.upTv);
            downTv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.downTv);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {


        View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.upTv.setText(mDataset[position]);
        holder.downTv.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has this concept of intent. It is used to start activities as well as passing messages between components.
In your `onBindViewHolder` add:

```
holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fname", mDataset[position]);
            intent.putExtra("lname", mDataset[position]);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

cheers!